# Relating or related information

Tags: grammar

I do not fully understand the uses of "relating" and "related". I have read the explanation of the uses of "relating to" and "related to". Yet, when it comes to how to choose between them when it's used as an adjective, I still feel vague.

Should I say:
I have found some related information to the topic.
Or I have found some relating information to the topic.

Why either one?

Answer (score 0):

These two sentences are both correct:

> I have found some **related** information on the topic.
>
> I have found some information **relating** to the topic.

The second sentence is similar to

> I have found some information which relates to the topic.

Perhaps these sentences will help you see what's going on:

> I don't like cooked carrots.
>
> There are some carrots cooking on the stove -- would you turn down the heat, please?

and

> Some interesting ideas were floated at the meeting.  =>  I'd like to follow up on some of those floated ideas.
>
> There's a little bug floating in my water.  May I have another glass, please?

Comment: How about the meaning? Are they different?

Comment: Yes.  Oh dear -- I was hoping the sentences I constructed for you would show you how this works.